# LM317 does not regulate 12V to 8.2V

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, lm317, fault

I am working on a project for which I needed to design a small linear regulator circuit in order to supply 8.2V for reading out sensors. I chose to use LM317, since it is quite simple to design and created the schematic below where input voltage is a standard 12V:

[image]

When I started testing the circuit I noticed that the output of the regulator was 7.9V just 0.3V short of what is required to supply. I tried increasing the input voltage to get the desired output but the regulator stays at 7.9V. What could be the issue?

Comment: What's the load on the output? The 317 has a minimum load, and I don't think your resistor divider is sufficient to provide it here. Also, have you accounted for Iadj?

Comment: Also you don't specify accuracy of the resistors. Are they 1% or 5%?

Comment: "Headroom" voltage required is min 3 V ... It is just ...

Comment: Check your math for R11 and R15.  The equation is in the datasheet.

Comment: @AnalogKid The math is right, should give 8.17V with ideal resistors. Now of course if the resistors are 5% and the lower part goes in one direction and the upper part in the other... But more likely as mentioned, it requires a certain minimum load to work reliably.

Comment: Load between 3.5 mA and 10 mA ...

Comment: If maintaining a minimum external load is a problem, delete R17 and recalculate.  Now there will be at least 10 mA through the adjustment resistor string, independent of any external load.

Comment: The purpose of a voltage regulator is to maintain the output voltage constant regardless of output load OR INPUT VOLTAGE, so adjusting the input voltage should have no effect on the output voltage, as long as the input voltage is sufficiently above the output voltage to allow the regulator to work.  Your output voltage is only 3% low.  That can probably be accounted for by component tolerances and meter accuracy.

Comment: There are dozens of different LM317 models with different parameters. Which exact model you bought? Link to datasheet of that specific purchase please. While measuring, did you measure what is voltage on ADJ vs ground, or OUT vs ADJ?

Comment: @Hearth my output load is 10kOhms.

Comment: @Lundin my components have 1% tolerance

Comment: @Antonio51 do you mean I should have designed for higher input voltage?

Comment: @Justme it's LM317MDCY. https://nl.farnell.com/Search?storeId=10168&catalogId=15001&categoryName=&selectedCategoryId=&langId=31&categoryIdBox=&st=LM317MDCY